# In candy box 2 what do the symbols on the status bar corners mean?

Tags: candy-box-2

In candy box 2 when I click the corners of the status bar the symbols change, does this do anything?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code, it does not appear to do anything other than change the appearance of the status bar. You can switch between 7 different options; but the variable that holds which option has been selected, "statusBarCornerStep", is never read except when drawing the status bar.